# How to get count value of a ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, properties

I have a model Post with a ManyToManyField field "User":

```
class Post(models.Model):
STATIC_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published')
)


title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'blog_posts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField()

likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'likes', blank = True)
upvotes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = STATIC_CHOICES, default = 'draft')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def total_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("post_detail", args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

I understand that the method `total_likes()`returns the number of likes in the views.  However, I want to display the number of likes in the `upvotes`IntegerField's default value.  Basically, if I could do something like:

```
upvotes = models.IntegerField(default = total_likes())
```

so that the number of likes show up as the default value in the IntegerField in the admin.  However, since I cannot do that, what is the best way so that I can get the number of `likes` to show up in the IntegerField in `upvotes`?

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `QuerySet` of the `Post`s with the number of likes with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.annotate(
    total_likes=Count('likes')
)
```

The `Post` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.total_likes` with the number of likes.

You thus do not need to store the number of upvotes. This is often better since this avoids *data duplication*.

Comment: Does this show up in the IntegerField though? I would like to have the option to edit the value of likes.

Comment: @WannaInternet: no, this is each time determined by the database. By making it a field, it is eventually possible that the number of likes would be out of sync, because for example a user is removed, or for `bulk_create`/`bulk_update` that circumvent trigggers.